# How to get actual frame of view after applying rotation, pan, pinch?

Tags: ios

I have a view with multiple subviews, each view handle pan, rotation, pinch. Now i want to save frame of each view to draw frame at same position latter.
I found many answers related to my question but no one solving my problem. please help.

[image]

Comment: I think better than frame you need to keep, center, rotation and width heigth for all your components

Comment: Yes but not able to get height and width. Any way to get @ Reinier

Comment: Can you share some code?, you are using view?, collection view? i need details in order to help you, best regards